# Why 1^NA is 1 but 1*NA is NA?

Tags: r

This is very basic question. `1^NA` gives `1`, but `1*NA` gives `NA`.
Any other numeric such as `1.1` or `2` to the power of `NA` gives `NA`
Is there a way to set an option which would give `1^NA` as `NA`?

Comment: See [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) under the heading `Function definition`.

Comment: There is no logical reason to make `1^NA` to return `NA`. `NA` in R is just a place holder for some unknown value. But 1 in power of any number will still be 1. Hence, no reason to say "We don't know which value would that be". It's the same like saying "*If we have `x * 2 = 6`, we don't know what `x` is*"- but we do.

Comment: David, counter example: 1^(NA+1i)

Comment: @thc I don't know complex numbers well enough to know.

Comment: I don't think NA is defined mathematically really.  It just seems to be an interesting programming quirk.